# Limit log level for an android process

Tags: android, log-level

I'm trying to limit the log level for the process **/system/bin/mm-qcamera-daemon** because when the camera strats working (recording video) it generates a lot of logs similar to the following entries:

```
   03-13 12:04:00.241   602  3224 I mm-camera: <ISP   >< INFO> 6602: isp_util_print_meta_stream_info: Deallocate resources
   03-13 12:04:00.241   602  3224 E mm-camera: <ISP   ><ERROR> 2121: isp_resource_unlink_modules: vfe 0 isp_submod_ports 0xf1d0b480 port parent linearization40
   03-13 12:04:00.243   602  3224 E mm-camera: <ISP   ><ERROR> 2028: isp_stream_resource_deallocate: res_alloc->num_streams 1
   03-13 12:04:00.243   602  3224 E mm-camera: <ISP   ><ERROR> 2028: isp_stream_resource_deallocate: res_alloc->num_streams 0
   03-13 12:04:00.243   602  3224 E mm-camera: <ISP   ><ERROR> 1923: isp_resource_free_isp: session 1 hw_id 0 
   03-13 12:04:00.244   602  3224 E mm-camera: <ISP   ><ERROR> 990: isp_resource_reserve_isp: dual_dbg single vfe reserved 1,request op pix clk 460000000
   03-13 12:04:00.244   602  3224 E mm-camera: <ISP   ><ERROR> 1111: isp_resource_reserve_isp: Reserved 1
   03-13 12:04:00.245   602  3224 I mm-camera: <ISP   >< INFO> 2545: isp_resource_allocate: INFO: ISP resource acquired: sess

   03-13 12:04:00.263   602  3710 I mm-camera: <MCT   >< INFO> 4531: mct_pipeline_stop_session_thread: Stop module name: pproc - X
   03-13 12:04:00.264   602   602 I mm-camera: <MCT   >< INFO> 4811: mct_pipeline_stop_session: Modules left: 5
   03-13 12:04:00.264   602  3711 I mm-camera: <MCT   >< INFO> 4523: mct_pipeline_stop_session_thread: Stop module name: imglib - E
   03-13 12:04:00.264   602   602 I mm-camera: <MCT   >< INFO> 4811: mct_pipeline_stop_session: Modules left: 4
   03-13 12:04:00.265   602  3708 I mm-camera: <MCT   >< INFO> 4531: mct_pipeline_stop_session_thread: Stop module name: isp - X
   03-13 12:04:00.265   602   602 I mm-camera: <MCT   >< INFO> 4811: mct_pipeline_stop_session: Modules left: 3
   03-13 12:04:00.266   602  3709 I mm-camera: <MCT   >< INFO> 4531: mct_pipeline_stop_session_thread: Stop module name: stats - X
   03-13 12:04:00.267   602   602 I mm-camera: <MCT   >< INFO> 4811: mct_pipeline_stop_session: Modules left: 2
   03-13 12:04:00.267   602  3711 I mm-camera: <MCT   >< INFO> 4531: mct_pipeline_stop_session_thread: Stop module name: imglib - X
   03-13 12:04:00.267   602   602 I mm-camera: <MCT   >< INFO> 4811: mct_pipeline_stop_session: Modules left: 1
   03-13 12:04:00.271   602  3706 I mm-camera: <MCT   >< INFO> 4531: mct_pipeline_stop_session_thread: Stop module name: sensor - X
```

The camera works correctly, but I'm seeing high CPU usage by this process. I tried to limit the log-level of the process by using the following command but it doesn't seem to have an effect:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.mm-camera CRITICAL
```

Any help or hints are more than welcome.

PD: The device I'm using is not rooted so I can't create the **/data/local.prop** file which is another alternative to limit the log level as I read on other answers.

Answer (score -2):

Switch conventional logcat into terminal

```
$ ./adb logcat   // this for mac (I own mac so) you can search it for your own system.
```